Repeating last page opened in .NET when using ShowDialog()
In my sales application, when making a sale that requires payment in credit and with a discount, we will open a 'pop-up' twice. The first one is to add the credit payment, and a while later, a pop-up will open regarding the approval of the discount on the sale. Both are opened using the same method.
However, when opening the discount approval screen, even updating the url to this new screen, when executing ShowDialog() the screen opened is the last one (payment in credit), so I think that the cache itself is overwriting something.
This is the method:
  public static void AbrirTelaWeb(string url, string titulo, Func<string, string> funcaoRetornoComRetorno, Action<string> funcaoSemRetorno, bool abrirComToken, TamanhoPaginaWeb tamanhoPagina, bool showDialog)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!Sincronizador.ConexaoDisponivel())
                {
                    ServicoNotificacao.Notificar(Resources.TituloErroConexao, IconeNotificacao.Fracasso);
                    return;
                }

                var funcao = funcaoRetornoComRetorno != null ? funcaoRetornoComRetorno.ToString() : "null";

                LoggerPOS.Instancia.GravarDebug($" - AbrirTelaWeb - {url}, {titulo}, {funcao}");

                if (!ExisteUrl())
                {
                    CaixaMensagemPOS.MostrarMensagemAtencao(string.Format("Não foi encontrado uma URL cadastrada para o produto {0}.", DescricaoApiVF));
                    return;
                }
                var urlBase = ServicoAutenticacao.ProdutosUrls[DescricaoApiVF];

                var Token = ServicoAutenticacao.Token;
                var urlVendaFacil = url.Contains("token")
                    ? $"{urlBase}{url.Replace("token", Token.ToString())}"
                    : $"{urlBase}{url}";

                if (abrirComToken)
                    urlVendaFacil += $"?key={Token}";

                if (Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2 == null)
                    Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2 = new TelaWebView2();

                Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.AtualizarEnderecoComRetorno(urlVendaFacil, funcaoRetornoComRetorno, funcaoSemRetorno, titulo);
                Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.AtualizarTamanho(tamanhoPagina);

                if (showDialog)
                {
                    Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.ShowDialog();
                }
                else
                {
                    Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.Show();
                    Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.Exibir();
                }


                LoggerPOS.Instancia.GravarDebug($" - AbrirTelaWeb - Fim -");
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LoggerPOS.Instancia.GravarExcecao(e);
            }
        }

I noticed that if it does not enter if(showdialog) and therefore, instead of executing Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.ShowDialog(); execute Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.Show(); and Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.Exibir(); the error does not occur, the screen opened will be the discount approval screen.(however, it does not open instantly and therefore cannot be used to correct it.)
We should to consider that Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2 is of type TelaWebView2 which inherits from the Window class..
How can I open the right window? Since I am already changing the URL inside 'AtualizarEnderecoComRetorno' that has the next code
  public void AtualizarEnderecoComRetorno(string url, Func<string, string> funcaoRetorno, Action<string> funcaoSemRetorno, string titulo)
        {
            pageTitle.labelTitulo.Content = titulo;
            /*if (webView.Source.ToString() == url)
                webView.Source = new Uri(string.Empty);*/
            if (webView.Source != null && webView.Source.ToString() == url)
                webView.Source = new Uri("https://erp.microvix.com.br");

            webView.Source = new Uri(url);
            FuncaoRetorno = funcaoSemRetorno;

            if (funcaoRetorno != null)
            {
                InformacoesWeb.Dados = funcaoRetorno.Invoke(String.Empty);
            }

        }```



Tried executing  Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2 = new TelaWebView2(); but the opened window was all blank.
Tried executing Sessao.Atual.TelaWebView2.Close() but didn't solve the problem.

